# Read key press on a bluetooth keyboard

Tags: c, linux, bluetooth

In my linux program I need to read the key presses on a bluetooth keyboard.
I tried to follow a set of examples using libbluetooth, but have so far no success.

At the last stage I am totally confused on what API to use.
As I understood, the library provides SDP and HCI interfaces and they both seem to be suitable for my need. I even could read out some information about the keyboard, but I cannot get further how to receive key presses.

So, I need you help to understand:

- do I need in general to use the libbluetooth or I have to use native BT sockets?
- assuming, that I do need to use the lib, which API to use: SDP or HCI (perhaps another..)?
- is the lib only required to initiate data transfer from the BT device, or also to receive the data

Comment: Bluetooth keyboard implements Bluetooth HID profile. You can use any kind of lib but better to use l2cap socket connection and receive HID packets from your keyboard. (Of course, if the keyboard is not something special)

Comment: In this case, do I need to initiate the transfer anyhow, perhaps with some sequence our smth. like that?

Comment: I am not so familiar with HID profile but on first look it is very similar to USB HID. SDP provides device descriptors (as in USB) and HID control channel implemented above L2CAP. You can find full HID specification there: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/profiles-overview